# If I am in an actual self defense situation, which is better, punching or palm strikes?

Tags: self-defense, self-training, punching

Is it overall better to use punches on an assailant or palm strikes? I don't want to break my fingers when punching, but is punching safer? Or should I switch to palm strikes?

Comment: Maybe relevant: [Closed fist vs open hand for head strikes](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/questions/12694/when-executing-head-strikes-does-the-increased-range-of-a-closed-fist-outweigh)

Answer (score 4):

This depends on a few things

1. Are you wearing boxing/mma gloves?

If you are then punch away! you might have trouble with a palm strike anyway.

2. What are you hitting?

It's very different suggesting a palm strike to the face (which makes sense) to a palm strike to the stomach solar plexus or liver (which really doesn't).

Sometimes you will hear the phrase: "Hit hard targets soft and soft targets hard"  from Kung Fu practitioners.  It's not always right but it's not bad as a rough guide.

3. Have you conditioned your hands into calloused lumps with over calcified knuckles?

If your hand looks like this:

[image: Calloused hands from punching a makiwara]

you probably know how to punch to the face.

4. How good are you with punches compared with palm strikes?

Palm strikes also put the fingers in danger if you leave them extended.  If your punching form is good and you have practiced hitting with the correct two knuckles it may be safer then the palm strike.  If you have practiced the palm strike more then stick with that.